# SSL Handshake error using Curl to POST a file to a web service

Tags: ssl, curl

I've been playing around with Curl, trying to do what should be a simple POST of a file to a web service for a couple of days and not getting anywhere.

The target POST service is unauthenticated HTTPS.  When trying to run my POST request via Curl or via Informatica, I am getting an SSL handshake failure with both methods.

For example:

```
curl -X POST -F 'file=@filename.dat' https://url
```

I have been able to get this to work using Postman, so I know the service works.  According to network security, SSL is disabled in this environment. Am I out of luck, or is there a way to get this to work without SSL?

Specific error encountered:
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: and also provide any error information, error text or codes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a client establishing a HTTPS URL connection will check the validity of a SSL certificate - otherwise, what's the point of using SSL?

In your case, you are saying "Pretend to use HTTPS but actually, ignore the certificate", because it's invalid, or you are still getting one, or you are in the development phase (I hope the latter is true, and get or create a valid sever certificate when needed).

But `curl` doesn't know that. It is assuming you are asking it to establish a connection with an HTTPS endpoint - thus it will try to validate the certificate - which, in your case, may be the source of the failure.

Try `curl -k -X POST -F 'file=@filename.dat' https://url`
From the manpage:

> ```
> -k, --insecure
>           (TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even for server connections otherwise considered insecure.
>
>           The server connection is verified by making sure the server's certificate contains the right name and verifies successfully using the cert store.
>
>           See this online resource for further details:
>            https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
>           See also --proxy-insecure and --cacert.
> ```

Comment: I've tried the insecure option without success, but I do see there are no certificates installed currently. I am running on version 7.27 so I'll try and get the server team to bump the version over 7.40 to ensure that's not the only issue.